# QGraphicsScene, QTextEdit and lost focus

Tags: c++, qt5

QTextEdit and similar widgets embedded in QGraphicsScene lose focus after using standard context menu (copy/paste), i. e. you need to click on QTextEdit again to continue editing. Scene emits focusItemChanged with newFocusItem==0.

First question: Is it a bug or standard behavior?

My investigation shows that function QGraphicsItemPrivate::setVisibleHelper() clears focus here:

```
if (hasFocus && scene) {
    // Hiding the focus item or the closest non-panel ancestor of the focus item
    QGraphicsItem *focusItem = scene->focusItem();
    bool clear = true;
    if (isWidget && !focusItem->isPanel()) {
        do {
            if (focusItem == q_ptr) {
                clear = !static_cast<QGraphicsWidget *>(q_ptr)->focusNextPrevChild(true);
                break;
            }
        } while ((focusItem = focusItem->parentWidget()) && !focusItem->isPanel());
    }
    if (clear)
        clearFocusHelper(/* giveFocusToParent = */ false, hiddenByPanel);
}
```

QGraphisItem has undocumented (internal) flag QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusScope. If the flag is set for QTextEdit's proxy-item it gets focus back after menu, but in any case focus cleared at first and after that Item receives it again or not.

Second Question: What is flag QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusScope for?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusScope` is for [FocusScope](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-focusscope.html) QML item. QtQuick1 is QGraphicsScene based and used that flag.

I'm not sure about side effects but that helps:

```
auto edit = new QLineEdit();
auto item = scene->addWidget(edit);
item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemFlag::ItemIsPanel);
```

Tested on Qt 5.9, Linux

---

**EDIT**

For me looks as bug:

- add `QLineEdit` to scene
- click to focus `QLineEdit`
- hit ContextMenu key to show context menu
- hit Esc key to exit context menu
- try to type

Expected: `QLineEdit` is focused and text appears

Actual: `QLineEdit` lost input focus

Please find it or report with [Qt bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io)

So it's OK to have workaround using `QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusScope` flag for example.

```
#if (QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(<fixed in Qt version>))
// it's workaround of bug QTBUG-...
#    if (QT_VERSION == QT_VERSION_CHECK(<version you are develop with>)
    item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusScope);
#    else
#        error("The workaround is not tested on this version of Qt. Please run tests/bug_..._workaround_test")
#    endif
```

Comment: Антон Сергунов, ItemIsPanel flag totally disallows focus in Qt 5.6.2.

Comment: I've tested on Linux, Qt 5.9

Comment: @Guest2016 Edited the answer. Please check

Comment: I have checked 5.7.1 and 5.9.1 on Linux.

If the flag ItemIsPanel is set for a proxy item, focus does not work immediately after the qt app starts.
To make it work It is necessary to switch to another app and return back.

Moreover if we have two QTextEdits: the first in QMainWindow and the second in QGraphicsScene, after the second switch/return we can see two blinking cursors simultaneously (in the both QLineEdits).